# Button that moves when scrolling disappears prematurely when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that only appears when a certain section on my webpage has been reached, and it's supposed to disappear when the user scrolls past this section.

When the user clicks the button, extra information pops up in the section.
The problem is, this extends the page, and then the button--if near the end of the section--disappears.

```js
//App.js stuff--I'm setting a manual distance here for when the button should disappear

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#detailButton").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var dbSearch = $("#search").offset().top;
    var contactPage = 4500;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > dbSearch && $(window).scrollTop() < contactPage) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#detailButton").show(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
        else{
            $("#detailButton").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//Index.html stuff

<section id="search" class="search">
   ...//detailButton should be shown here 
</section>


<section id="contact" class="closing-header">
...//last part of page--detailButton show be hidden here
</section>
```

I need a way to ensure that the button only disappears when it moves on to the last section (#contact). How can I do this?

Comment: Your title is confussing

Comment: I know. A suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Button movement with collaboration of scrolling on click, i guess this title should be better

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the offset in scroll function.

```js
//App.js stuff

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#detailButton").hide(); //hide your div initially
   
    $(window).scroll(function() {
         var dbSearch = $("#search").offset().top;
         var contactPage = 4500;
        if($(window).scrollTop() > dbSearch && $(window).scrollTop() < contactPage) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#detailButton").show(); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
        else{
            $("#detailButton").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
//Index.html stuff

<section id="search" class="search">
   ...//detailButton should be shown here 
</section>


<section id="contact" class="closing-header">
...//last part of page--detailButton show be hidden here
</section>
```